# Is binding processing in Knockout.js 2.3 synchronous?

Tags: knockout.js

After an observable value is changed (for example a number of items in an observable array) is rendering of the view happening synchronously?

What I am concerned about is if any other JavaScript code can be executed before the view rendering (and possibly processing of all dependent computeds) is over.

Because JavaScript is single threaded, if processing of changed value is synchronous, then my understanding is that no other JavaScript code can be executed and no user action (e.g. changes of input values) can be processed.

Is this correct or are there any other things to be considered when binding processing takes some time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Observables notify subscribers synchronously and immediately. Each subscriber is notified in the order it subscribed. Many of those subscribers will be computed observables, which will immediately update themselves and notify their subscribers, etc. Updating the DOM is done by binding handlers, which use computed observables to track dependencies and run updates.

So, updating the DOM is synchronous. But you asked about "rendering of the view". Rendering is done by the browser whenever it wants to do so. It may be synchronous, but it usually isn't.

Comment: I am a little bit confused. My understanding is that your answer is kind of opposite to the answer of @PWKad . Or am I reading it wrongly?

Comment: @PWKad seems wrong. But maybe he's thinking of the [Deferred Updates](https://github.com/mbest/knockout-deferred-updates) plugin, which does use a queue for updates.

Comment: @MichaelBest how?  Observable subscriptions do not stop the currently executing thread to update and then resume, they update immediately as the thread opens up.  If you want to see it in action put an alert in a custom binding handler and one in a computed and change the observable that the computed is subscribed to.  The computed updates first every time, unless you are saying I am wrong about something else.  To further elaborate create a long running script and change the observable and watch that the dom isn't updated until the script releases the thread

Comment: As I said in my answer, each subscriber is notified in the order it subscribed. Usually a computed set up in the view model will be initialized before binding are initialized through `ko.applyBindings`, which is why you get the alerts in the order you do, but you could set up a scenario where the binding runs first.

Comment: I also made a distinction between updating the DOM, which happens in JavaScript, and rendering the view, which the browser usually does after the current JavaScript "thread" is complete.

Answer (score -1):

The observables will notify their subscribers in order, when the thread opens up.

Take a look at this article -

http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

When your observable updates, the subscription updates will be added to the queue.  If something else is already there, it will be evaluated first.  JavaScript is synchronous by nature but can be 'tricked' into being asynchronous by promises, but that is not how the observables work.

Comment: So the processing of observables is added to the end of the queue. But what about the rendering of the html? Is it happening synchronously and is on the same thread?

Comment: Step through with the debugger and watch how it works